# Using some OpenSSL functions on Windows without installing it

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, openssl

I am trying to port one Linux program to Windows. This Linux program uses some functions from OpenSSL:

```
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/dh.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/rc4.h>
```

As you can see, it only uses few common cryptographic functions: Diffie-Hellman, SHA, HAMC, RC4

The end users on Windows have to install OpenSSL to make the program run, which is not user friendly.

Can I use these cryptographic functions without asking the users to install the OpenSSL? (like static linking dll?)

Comment: Try dynamically linking to OpenSSL via `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the library (libs), DLL files and header files to your application build directory structure, refer and link it via linker option.
Yes, you have to ship DLL files from OpenSSL with your application.